# Android Macrobenchmark module doesn't recognise 'com.android.test' plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-multi-module, macrobenchmark

I'm trying to put the MacroBenchmark library in my project, but I'm getting an error to apply `com.android.test` the plugin. This error happens while syncing Gradle.

I've added the plugin root gradle using the same AGP version (7.3.1). I'm also using Kotlin 1.7.10.

The benchmark module is inside a sub-package and not at the root of the project.

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.test']
> Failed to apply plugin class 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin'.
   > Extension of type 'TestedExtension' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [ExtraPropertiesExtension, SonarQubeExtension, Property<ModuleType>, ReportingExtension, DetektExtension, LibrariesForLibs, VersionCatalogsExtension, BasePluginExtension, DefaultArtifactPublicationSet, SourceSetContainer, JavaToolchainService, JavaPluginExtension, NamedDomainObjectContainer<BaseVariantOutput>, TestExtension, TestAndroidComponentsExtension]
```

I tried to remove this plugin just to build and see if was possible to run some benchmarks. Without success.
After removing the plugin I get an error on the:

```
android {
    ...

    targetProjectPath = ":app"
    ...
}

> Could not set unknown property 'targetProjectPath' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
```

If I remove this `targetProjectPath` the project builds, but it isn't possible to run any tests.

BTW, I tested it using Android Studio 2022.2.1 Canary 9 and 2021.3.1 Patch 1

**EDIT:**

Root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    apply from: "./buildSystem/android-config.gradle"

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:${libs.versions.kotlin.get()}"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.test' version '7.3.1' apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.crashlytics) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.services) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.quadrant) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.sonarqube)

    alias(libs.plugins.test.gradle.retry) apply false

    // Core-lib plugins
    alias(libs.plugins.corelib.detekt)
    alias(libs.plugins.corelib.googlePlayReleaseNotes)
    alias(libs.plugins.corelib.moduleDependenciesCheck)
    alias(libs.plugins.corelib.coverage)
}
```

Macrobenchmark gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.test'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.benchmark'
    compileSdk 33

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        // This benchmark buildType is used for benchmarking, and should function like your
        // release build (for example, with minification on). It's signed with a debug key
        // for easy local/CI testing.
        benchmark {
            debuggable = true
            signingConfig = debug.signingConfig
            matchingFallbacks = ["release"]
        }
    }

    targetProjectPath = ":app"
    experimentalProperties["android.experimental.self-instrumenting"] = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.benchmark:benchmark-macro-junit4:1.1.1'
}

androidComponents {
    beforeVariants(selector().all()) {
        enabled = buildType == "benchmark"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you publish your root `build.gradle` and `macrobenchmark/build.gradle`?

Comment: @ConstOrVar done! The `macrobenchmark/build.gradle` is auto-generated by Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure out (with my teammates' help) what was wrong with it.
We were removing `TestedExtension` from our project. After fixing the plugin, was possible to create the benchmark module without any issues.